# PHP form and Ajax My form add the post two times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi I make a form with Ajax but whenever I click the submit button ajax send to data two times. I use the *var postData = null;* but ajax didn't work. But if I use the just PHP my form is working correctly. But I need the ajax :)

***normal_form.js***

```
$(function() {
    $("#form-msg").hide()  ;
$("#simple-post").click(function()
{
    $("#ajaxform").submit(function(e)
    {
        $("#form-msg").html("<div class='preloader'></div>");
        var postData = $("#ajaxform").serializeArray();
        var formURL = $("#ajaxform").attr("action");
        $.ajax(
        {
            url : formURL,
            type: "POST",
            data : postData,
            cache:false,
            success:function(data)

            {
                if($("#ajaxform").attr("data-rel") == "reset"){
                document.getElementById("ajaxform").reset();
                $("#form-msg").show(300)  ;
                $("#form-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">'+data+'</code></pre>');
                $("body").click( function() { $("#form-msg").hide(400); });
                }
                else{
                $("#form-msg").show(300)  ;
                $("#form-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">'+data+'</code></pre>');
                $("body").click( function() { $("#form-msg").hide(400); });
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
            {
                $("#form-msg").fadeIn(300)  ;
            $("#form-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">AJAX Request Failed<br/> textStatus='+textStatus+', errorThrown='+errorThrown+'</code></pre>');
            $("#form-msg").click( function() { $(this).slideToggle(); });
                $("body").click( function() { $("#form-msg").fadeOut(500); });
                $("#form-msg").fadeOut(8000)  ;
                        }
        });

        e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
        e.unbind();
    });
    $("#ajaxform").submit(); //I'm supposed to delete it.
});
```

});

Ps. You see, my English is not good. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that sticks out very obviously is that you are submitting the form twice:

```
$("#ajaxform").submit(function(e) //5th line from the top
```

...and:

```
$("#ajaxform").submit(); //SUBMIT FORM
```

Yes, no doubt. Your entire code sample can be reduced to this:

```
$("#ajaxform").submit('a bunch of stuff you are doing here');
$("#ajaxform").submit();
```

Take out your last `$("#ajaxform").submit();` and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks bro this answer is correct. It's does not add 2 times. Sorry I wait for click Correct Answer :) .